# LTspice simulation is too slow

Tags: motor, ltspice, inverter, rectifier

I am currently simulating the a AC/DC/AC motor with the rectifier and the inverter stage. The motor is simulated as a L,R and a back EMF. The problem is that my simulation is too slow (practically more than 30 mins for 1 cycle of trans).

I have already tried and made the rectifier (simple diode) and inverter (ideal PWM switches) stages as simple as possible (they run individually in a mater of seconds).

Is there some way to make the simulation faster?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4Gduo.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

```
Vga L1 COM SINE(0 {Vac} {fg} 0 0 0) AC 1 0 
Lgra L1 N001 {Lg} 
Rgra N001 N002 {Rg}
Rgrb N006 N007 {Rg}
Lgrb L2 N006 {Lg}
Lgrc L3 N010 {Lg}
Rgrc N010 N011 {Rg}
Vgb L2 COM SINE(0 {Vac} {fg} 0 0 120) AC 1 120
Vgc L3 COM SINE(0 {Vac} {fg} 0 0 -120) AC 1 -120
R1 COM 0 10Meg
XX1 N002 N007 N011 Vdc 0 diode_rectifier
XX2 Vdc 0 N003 N008 N012 3_ph_inverter
C1 Vdc 0 {Cdc}
L1 N003 N004 {Lload}
L2 N008 N009 {Lload}
L3 N012 N013 {Lload}
R2 N004 N005 {Rload}
R3 N009 N005 {Rload}
R4 N013 N005 {Rload}
V1 N003 N004 SINE(0 {Vload} {fg})
V2 N012 N004 SINE(0 {Vload} {fg} 0 0 120)
V3 N017 N004 SINE(0 {Vload} {fg} 0 0 -120)

 * block symbol definitions
.subckt diode_rectifier Va Vb Vc V+ V-
D1 Va V+ D
D2 Vb V+ D
D3 Vc V+ D
D4 V- Vc D
D5 V- Va D
D6 V- Vb D
.ends diode_rectifier

.subckt 3_ph_inverter Vdcp Vdcm Va Vb Vc
V7 sine1 0 SINE(0 0.87 {fg} 0)
V8 tri 0 PULSE(-1 1 0 {1/(2*fsw)} {1/(2*fsw)} 0 {1/fsw})
B1 1H 0 V=V(sine1)>V(tri)+0.05
B2 1L 0 V=V(sine1)<V(tri)
V3 sine2 0 SINE(0 0.87 {fg} 0 0 -120)
V5 sine3 0 SINE(0 0.87 {fg} 0 0 120)
B3 2H 0 V=V(sine2)>V(tri)+0.05
B4 2L 0 V=V(sine2)<V(tri)
B5 3H 0 V=V(sine3)>V(tri)+0.05
B6 3L 0 V=V(sine3)<V(tri)
DA+ Va Vdcp mydiode
S§TA+ Vdcp Va 1H 0 MySwitch
DA- Vdcm Va mydiode
S§TA- Va Vdcm 1L 0 MySwitch
DB+ N001 Vdcp mydiode
S§TB+ Vdcp Vb 2H 0 MySwitch
DB- Vdcm N001 mydiode
S§TB- Vb Vdcm 2L 0 MySwitch
DC- Vdcm Vc mydiode
S§TC- Vc Vdcm 3L 0 MySwitch
DC+ Vc Vdcp mydiode
S§TC+ Vdcp Vc 3H 0 MySwitch
.model MySwitch SW (Ron=.001 Roff=10Meg Vt=0.5)
.model mydiode D
.ends 3_ph_inverter

.model D D
.lib C:\Users\NVA\Documents\LTspiceXVII\lib\cmp\standard.dio
.param Vac = 230V
.param fg=50Hz
.param Lg = 0.7mH
.param Rg =0.05
.param Cdc =50u
;ac oct 100 1 100k
;tran 0 {30/fsw} {21/fsw} {0.001/fsw}
.tran 0 {2/fg} {1/fg} {0.001/fg}
.param fsw=10kHz
.param Lload=2.5mH 
+ Rload = 3 
+Vload=200
```

Comment: I want to my transient simulation for 1 50Hz period

Comment: There are many things one could make "wrong" in the simulation, but to point those out, we need to see it. Most common thing is using ideal parts instead of actual ones. Best would be to make the .asc file available for people to poke at.

Comment: also if I make the "motor" inductances small (in the range of 1uH) then the simulation runs fine

Comment: How do I upload the .asc file?

Comment: Generally if something is oscillating somewhere it kills the simulation speed. Figure out what is bouncing and fix it and it will run a lot faster.

Comment: Have you tried the alternate solver? Control panel -> SPICE -> solver = Alternate.

Comment: What time step are you using. Hint... don't use femto seconds LOL

Comment: I changed the tolerance, and switched between normal and alternate solutions. It seems to work better now.

Comment: post your .net file

Comment: @NikosVandoros Please use the "edit" utility to edit your post, then repost as a `code` block (see in the edit tools). From the start I would guess your diodes need `epsilon` and `revepsilon` specified, and your switches reasonable values for the resistances and, possibly, negative hysteresis. As analogsystemsrf says, adding parasitics to the reactive elements won't hurt.

Answer (score 1):

Install 1Kohm resistors across each of the inductors, to speed convergence.

Comment: This makes it work really fast and without the need to increase tolerance. Thanks a lot

Comment: How much does this effect the solutions?

Comment: From the input point of view, it practically has zero effect. I am looking at the power factor, PWHD and THD values. Also the Vpp on the DC link capacitor remains the same. On the other hand without the resistor the sim won't complete unless I change the tolerance of SPICE. 

btw i put a 10k resistor in parallel instead of a 1k one.